# How can I cut a string after X characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I cut a string after a specific number of characters in JavaScript?

I then want to append the '…' Unicode character. How can I do this?

Comment: if you're planning to create an ellipsis effect, you could use CSS `text-overflow:ellipsis`, which will cut the string for you at the end of its box and give it an ellipsis, without you having to do any javacript.

Comment: @Spudley: There is a small downside though, all text is being loaded. Might not make a big difference in this situation, but if you (for example) use php to make something like a news-items-list you download all the text and then hide a part. Kinda a waste. Again, this can work perfectly fine here, just a small note or other users

Comment: @Martijn - well, he was asking about Javascript, so the assumption is that he's already got it in the browser. But yes, for very long text, you have a fair point.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Simply

```
  var trunc = "abcdef".substr(0, 3) + "\u2026";
```

Comment: A small check to see if the startString is not yet the substr length... If my input would be ABC, no dots should be added. Anything under (maxStrLen+numOfDots) should not get the dots because it would actually make it longer

Answer (score 16):

The other answers are great, but they always add an ellipsis. The following will only add an ellipsis if the string is too long:

```js
function truncateText(text, length) {
  if (text.length <= length) {
    return text;
  }

  return text.substr(0, length) + '\u2026'
}

let truncated;
truncated = truncateText('Hello, World!', 10);
console.log(truncated);
truncated = truncateText('Hello, World!', 50);
console.log(truncated);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var trucatedText = yourtext.substring(0, 3) + '...';  // substring(from, to);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sth like this?

```
var text= "This is your text";
var stripHere = 7;
var shortText = text.substring(0, stripHere) + "...";

alert(shortText);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ThKsw/

Answer (score 1):

This function should work. There is a character limit. if that limit exits only then the dots will be shown

```js
  turncateName(text: string): string{
    const characterLimit = 10;
    if(text.length>characterLimit){
      text = text.substr(0, characterLimit)+ "\u2026";
    }
    return text;
  }
  
console.log(turncateName("ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWXYZ"));
console.log(turncateName("ABCD"));
```